# How to show language switcher only on home page

Tags: nodes, blocks

In my multilanguage site i am using Language switcher (User interface text) and I have it located in block called "Help". This block is shown in the middle of the site, where I want it. But I want it to be displayed only on homepage. I tried to hide by the restriction of a content type. But I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set block visibility to only show on `<front>`